# develop android apps in xcode

Tags: android, xcode, macos

hi im trying to develop an android app in xcode. ive downloaded java, java jdk and the android sdk and have loaded a half finished (but working with no errors) app. i also changed the target to:

> Build Tool: /usr/bin/ant
>   Arguments: install

but when i try to build it i get

> Build file build.xml does not exist

i couldn't figure out how to make my own build.xml so downloaded one but still no luck. Id really appreciate some help.

Comment: Xcode is rarely used as the IDE for a Java-based project. Is there additional context you can give? (For example RN and Expo are cross platform|mobile solutions

Answer (score -1):

(I couldn't resist a a couple quick googles).

Apple provides documentation for this -> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/02-JavaDevTools/JavaDevTools.html

NOTE: This is in the developer archive, and very few people seem to use this environment.

All the actually discussions I found of this combination discouraged its use. If you can't find any active Java developers in the Play Store who say they do this, I would not spend time trying to make this work.

There are many sucessful Java developers using !Xcode on macOS.